# Is there a reference for fsi.commands?

Tags: f#, command, fsi

I'm trying to quiet down the F# Interactive terminal in VS Code. In my search I ran into commands such as fsi.ShowDeclarationVariables <- false, but I haven't found documentation of all such commands available. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not aware of any docs, but have you tried simply inspecting the `fsi` value? E.g. `[for m in fsi.GetType().GetProperties() -> m.Name]`

Answer (score 1):

There is some documentation for the members of the `fsi` object [available in the F# docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/interactive.interactivesession-class-%5bfsharp%5d). This is a bit tricky to find, because `fsi` is a value of type `InteractiveSession` and so you need to look for the type, rather than just for `fsi` value.

It is also worth noting that, in addition to using reflection to see the members, you can also see all members if you type `fsi` followed by `.` (at least in Visual Studio) and the names of the members are fairly descriptive (though figuring out the details is a bit fiddly sometimes).

I'm not sure if the documentation is complete, but the docs are hosted on GitHub and [anyone can contribute](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualfsharpdocs/blob/live/docs/conceptual/interactive.interactivesession-class-[fsharp].md) to improve them and add examples.